# Batch script to enforce inheritence on 3rd level folders

Tags: inheritance, for-loop, batch-file, acl

This is kind of an interesting problem, so please bear with me here:

I have three levels of nested folders used for syncing files to end-user devices - on the first level the administrator has permissions, on the second level the end-users have (explicit & individual) permissions, and on the third level there is content (files and usually more folders).

The problem arises when (occasionally) content being moved into the third level does not inherit the permissions from the folder above it - so our users end up with content in their directories that they don't have permissions to (and so, cannot sync the data).

To remedy this I am trying to write a batch script (to be run on a daily schedule) that digs into the third level folders and resets the inheritance flag on the ACLs there. It is important that this script does not touch the permissions on the second level folders (since it will remove the explicit rights for the end-users).

Here is the script I am working with (yes it's very simple):

```
SET base=C:\testPrivate
SET subfolders=.\*

FOR /r %base% %%a in (.) do 
        (
        icacls.exe %subfolders% /reset /t
        )
exit /b
```

The problem with the script I'm trying to build currently is that it resets the permissions on everything (including the second level) below whatever directory it is working on.

Is there a flag or variable I can use that takes the working directory of the /r flag and feeds it to %subfolders%, so that icacls only processes on the third level folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for looking into this with me - I managed to get my script to work with minor modification:

```
SET base=C:\testPrivate
SET CurrentDate=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%
SET CurrentTIme=%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%

FOR /d %%a in (%base%\*) do (icacls.exe %%a\* /t /reset >> %base%\InheritanceReset-%currentdate%.%currenttime%.txt)
exit /b
```

This batch script properly explores each 3rd level directory and resets inheritance on every object inside it, without modifying the parent (2nd level) or root (1st level) folder(s). It also outputs its actions to a date/time stamped log file.

I hope this will come in handy for somebody else out there - I know it had me scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove the `echo` if the output is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
pushd "c:\testPrivate"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a /b /s^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\') do echo icacls.exe "%%~fi" /reset /t
popd
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I got working with this:
`SET base=C:\testPrivate

FOR /d %%a in (%base%\*) do (
        icacls.exe %%a\* /t /reset >>%base%\output.txt
)
exit /b`

Comment: That's interesting, but OK: you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Endoro's code (remove the echo to enable the command) - but it works on the third level folder.  Is that good enough when setting permissions rather than setting them on the file itself?  Will they then inherit the permissions from the folder?

```
@echo off &setlocal
pushd "c:\testPrivate"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\ ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\') do echo icacls.exe "%%~fi" /reset /t
popd
pause
```

If not then this works on third level files:

```
@echo off &setlocal
pushd "c:\testPrivate"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b /s ^| findstr \\.*\\.*\\.*\\ ^| findstr /v \\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\') do echo icacls.exe "%%~fi" /reset /t
popd
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I got working with this:
`SET base=C:\testPrivate

FOR /d %%a in (%base%\*) do (
        icacls.exe %%a\* /t /reset >>%base%\output.txt
)
exit /b`